# If date one matches then order by date 2

Tags: sql, database, sql-order-by

I'm trying to do an order by where if the update time is the same then order by mod date

| Mod_Date | Update_tim |
| --- | --- |
| 7/28/2021 | 8/3/2021 |
| 7/26/2021 | 8/3/2021 |

Comment: Expressions specified in `order by` part are used to order result set by each successively from left to right: rows that were equally ranked by the left expression then ordered by rigth.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two keys in `order by`:

```
order by update_tim desc, mod_date desc
```

Based on the example, I assume you want a descending sort.